# Embed request fields from another .srv files into my .srv

Tags: ros, catkin, custom-message, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Service_Description_Specification](http://wiki.ros.org/srv#Service_Description_Specification) says:

> You cannot embed another .srv inside of a .srv.

The syntax of `.srv` files aligns with that of `msg` so there should be nothing specific to srv (it's just the format where request and response fields need to be defined is different). Is there any reason why we can't embed another .srv files into my .srv?

---

**UPDATE**: Reponding to the comment from @NEngelhard.
What I wanted to do is to import request fields from an existing .srv file into the request field of my .srv.

Then I've come to realize that importing an entire .srv file, which obviously includes both request and response fields, into the `request` field of my .srv would result in undesirable situation.

So I changed my title to ask if there's a way to import req fields only from existing .srv.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251444/embed-request-fields-from-another-.srv-files-into-my-.srv/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-01-07**:
How would you like to embed the inner service? If you integrate it into the request, then your new request would also include the result-definition of the inner service. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure this is not possible without much hacky fiddeling.

You could, however, create a `GeneralServiceRequest.msg` that you could include there, if you want.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1